# Save content of nm function into variable

Tags: bash

Need to save content of nm function into variable. Files, which nm should run are arguments of script.
Currently I have:

```
while [ $i -le $#]
do
  eval nm "\$$i"
  i=$(( i+1 ))
done
```

which list me nm result of each file.

But I need to save result of nm file into variable.
I tried

```
eval CONTENT=$(nm "\$$i")
```

but this show me error "nm: '$1': No such file."

Comment: `CONTENT=$(eval nm "\$$i")`

Comment: `bash` would let you avoid using `eval` here with `nm ${!i}`. Check the `bash` man page for indirect parameter expansion. But the right thing to do is to iterate over the position parameter themselves, not their names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@devnull has solved your immediate problem (in his comment), but I suggest you rewrite your loop as follows:

```
for f
do
  CONTENT=$(nm "$f")
  # ... work with $CONTENT
done
```

- A `for` loop without `in ...` implicitly loops over all arguments passed to the script.
- Since `f` will then directly contain the value of each argument, there is no need to use `eval`.

(As an aside, your original code won't run as posted, because the `[ ... ]` conditional will break for 2 reasons: (a) `$i` is not initialized and (b) the closing `]` must have a space before it.)

Comment: Thanks for reply, I'll try it later, because of time. For the other note, I rewrite it from another computer. In my script file, it is correctly written, but still, thanks for note.

Answer (score 0):

"eval" is part of the command you need to redirect:

```
CONTENT=$(eval nm "\$$i")
```

You will have to set up an array to store results tho:

```
CONTENT[$i]=$(eval nm "$\$$i")
```